# HTTP Accept-Language header validation regex

Tags: regex, http, header, pcre

I'm tying to validate HTTP Accept-Language header values using `PCRE` regex and i came up with this regex:

```
(?i:(?:\*|[a-z\-]{2,5})(?:;q=\d\.\d)?,)+(?:\*|[a-z\-]{2,5})(?:;q=\d\.\d)?
```

Two example of Accept-Language header values:

```
fr-CH,fr;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,*;q=0.5  

en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Is there a more optimized regex for this?

Comment: [HTTP RFC Accept Header](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.2)

Comment: I didn't go through RFC but yours could go shorter `(?i)((?:\*|[a-z-]{2,5})(?:;q=\d\.\d)?)(?:,(?-1))*`

Comment: @revo: It is better (and faster) than mine.

Comment: Seems you're talking about "Accept-Language", not "Accept", right?

Comment: @JulianReschke: Yes, I'm sorry ... I updated the question.

Comment: @revo: Please answer so i can accept yours. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sense of being shorter there would be a regex in order to substitute using capture groups and recursions:

```
(?i)((?:\*|[a-z-]{2,5})(?:;q=\d\.\d)?)(?:,(?1))*
```